# Show alert if CheckBox isn't pressed before signing up in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to oblige the user to press the CheckBox button before signing up, otherwise show alert saying "you should agree with our terms and policies". Here's my code that makes sure all the fields are not empty, i want to check if the checkbox is pressed too:

```
onSignUp(){
    if(
        this.state.email != '' &&
        this.state.password != '' &&
        this.state.name != '' 
      ){
        const { email, password, name } = this.state;
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) => {
            firebase.firestore().collection("Users")
                .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .set({
                    name,
                    email
                })
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
else{
    alert("Make sure you filled all the fields with correct info!");
}





}
```

CheckBox button

```
<Checkbox style={{padding:'5%'}}  color="primary" label="I agree with Terms & Policies" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a state for the checkbox, update it when the [value changes](https://github.com/react-native-checkbox/react-native-checkbox#common-props), and check it before creating the user. Or use the [`useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook to attach to the checkbox and check its value directly before creating the user.

Something like the following should work:

##### useState

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

export function MyComponent(props) {
  const [checkBoxState, setCheckBoxState]  = useState(false);
  const doSignUp = () => {
    if (!checkBoxState) {
      /* display a warning */
    } else {
      /* continue with sign up */
    }
  }
  return (
    <CheckBox
      value={checkboxState}
      onValueChange={setCheckBoxState}
    />
    {/* Have a button somewhere that calls doSignUp() */}
  );
}
```

##### useRef

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

export function MyComponent(props) {
  const checkBoxRef = useRef(null);
  const doSignUp = () => {
    if (!checkBoxRef.current.value) {
      /* display a warning */
    } else {
      /* continue with sign up */
    }
  }
  return (
    <CheckBox
      ref={checkBoxRef}
      value={false}
    />
    {/* Have a button somewhere that calls doSignUp() */}
  );
}
```